# Is there any way to modify the headers using declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules in Manifest v3?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

in my Chrome extension, I need to modify the header dynamically using "declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules". it works in the developer mode. But when uploading to webstore it doesn't support declarativeNetRequest. how to resolve this issue.

```
function modifyHeader() {
  if (settings.enabled) {
    chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules(
      {
        removeRuleIds: [1, 2, 3],
        addRules: [
          {
            id: 1,
            priority: 1,
            action: {
              type: "modifyHeaders",
              requestHeaders: [
                {
                  header: "x-geo",
                  operation: "set",
                  value: genUULE(),
                },
                {
                  header: "accept-language",
                  operation: "set",
                  value: genAcceptLanguage(),
                },
              ],
            },
            condition: {
              urlFilter: "||google.com/",
              resourceTypes: [
                "main_frame",
                "sub_frame",
                "image",
                "xmlhttprequest",
                "ping",
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      () => {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        }
      }
    );
  } else {
    chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules(
      {
        removeRuleIds: [1],
      },
      () => {
        console.log("removed");
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: declarativeNetRequest can be used by extensions in the web store. I guess you're using `onRuleMatchedDebug` which is only for debugging the local unpacked extensions. You can't use it in the web store, indeed. Anyway, show your code and we'll see if it can be rewritten properly.

Comment: yes you are correct in manifest permission I used "declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess", I think that's the problem

Comment: @wOxxOm can you please help me to solve this problem?
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76922112/chrome-webrequest-is-no-longer-supporting-manifest-v3-how-to-rewrite-the-code-so)

Comment: Show your code that uses declarativeNetRequest.

Comment: @wOxxOm check now.i added the code

Comment: The posted code works in the web store extension, so I guess there's something else wrong. Another frequent mistake is adding listeners inside chrome.runtime.onInstalled