# chrome.webRequest is no longer supporting Manifest V3.How to rewrite the code so that it support Manifest v3?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to update this code so that it works on Manifest v3.On searching I found that "chrome.webRequest" is not supported in Manifest v3 now. On the documentation, it says that use "chrome.declarativeNetRequest", but how to use it with "onAuthRequired" and "onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener " as in the given code

```
 Proxy.prototype.setProxy = function (
        proxyAddress,
        proxyUsername,
        proxyPassword
      ) {
        if (proxyAddress === undefined || proxyAddress.trim() === "") {
          setProxySettings(config())
            .then(() => {
              debugProxySettings();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error("Error setting proxy:", error);
            });
        } else {
          setProxySettings(config(proxyAddress))
            .then(() => {
              if (proxyAddress !== "" && proxyUsername !== "") {
                if (chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired) {
                  chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
                    function (details) {
                      return {
                        authCredentials: {
                          username: proxyUsername.trim(),
                          password: proxyPassword.trim(),
                        },
                      };
                    },
                    { urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
                    ["blocking"]
                  );
                } else {
                  chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
                    function (details) {
                      return credentialsToHeader(
                        details,
                        proxyUsername.trim(),
                        proxyPassword.trim()
                      );
                    },
                    { urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
                    ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]
                  );
                }
              }
              debugProxySettings(proxyUsername, proxyPassword);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error("Error setting proxy:", error);
            });
        }
      };
```

Comment: Judging by the documentation you can use chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired asynchronously by adding webRequestAuthProvider to `permissions`. Also remove `"blocking"` from js and `webRequestBlocking` from manifest.json.

Comment: @wOxxOm i am not using "webRequestBlocking" in js.
do I need to add any permission other than "webRequestAuthProvider"  for this"chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener"

Comment: webRequestBlocking is in manifest.json and you need to remove it if it's there, so if it's not then you don't need to remove it.

Comment: @wOxxOm ok. So removing "webRequestBlocking" in manifest.json and then adding "webRequestAuthProvider" to the permissions make this code work correctly right...

Answer (score 0):

Add this permissions to your manifest file

manifest.json

```json
"permissions": [
  "webRequest",
  "webRequestAuthProvider"
]
```

backgroung.js

```js
function authRequired() {
  function callbackFn(details, callback) {
    const response = {
      authCredentials: {
        username: username,
        password: password,
      },
    }
    callback(response)
  }
}

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
  callbackFn,
  { urls: ['<all_urls>'] },
  ['asyncBlocking']
)
}
```

This works for me